# Fatal Exception android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #291 in layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line

Tags: android, kotlin, crash, textinputlayout

I am seeing this crash from firebase,App is crashing for almost all android version and device are majorly samsung,vivo,xiaomi,huawei etc.
I have searched but most of reason i am seeing is related to theme in androidx,In my code i am not using theme.
In firebase i am seeing crash is in line 291 which is the below code.

This crash is not reproducible but on firebase i am seeing multiple crash.

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                                        android:id="@+id/email_error"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                        android:visibility="visible" />
```

**FireBaselogs:**
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.signin.SigninActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #291: Binary XML file line #291: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1839)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6864)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)

Comment: please show your android studio and firebase log to show what errors are you getting actually. also show your more relevant code of the error.

Comment: @ruben i am not able to reproduce this crash, so can't share android studio logs. Firebase logs i have add above.

Comment: It is something with inflating layout. From your above code it's not obvious. Please share more of your code